# Multiple if statements and while loops reassigning variable syntax error in bash script

Tags: bash

1. This is bash script that I wrote got an error.  That syntax error near unexpected token token 'fi'  I indicated the line where error message pointing at below.  I am not sure why getting this error.  Perhaps I made mistake in syntax.  Please help!

I wrote the same logic in other language at the bottom for your better understanding of my question.  I noticed that when using if statement in bash there are two syntax that `if [[ conditional statement ]]; then` and `if [ conditional statement ] then` I am also curious to know what is the difference between the two?  Thank you for all your help!

```
    #!/bin/bash


    groupadd SC001
    count=1
    userid=$(ls /home | wc -l)
    echo "##Total user is "$userid

    if [ $uesrid -lt 10 ] then
        while [ $count -lt 10 ] 
            do
                useradd -m "sc"$count"_2018"
                let "count+=1"
            done
    fi   <-----------------------------This is the line where error message pointing at lol

    count=10
    userid=$(ls /home | wc -l)
    if[ $uesrid -ge 10 ] then
        while [ $count -le 25 ] 
            do
                useradd -m "sc"$count"_2018"
                let "count+=1"
            done
    fi

################# Could be written in other language

    groupadd SC001
    int count = 1;
    int userid = userid=$(ls /home | wc -l);
    system.out.print("##Total user is "+userid);

    if (userid < 10){
        while (count < 10){
            useradd -m "sc"$count"_2018";
            count++;
        }
    }



    count=10;
    userid = userid=$(ls /home | wc -l);
    if (userid >= 10){
        while (count < 25){
            useradd -m "sc"$count"_2018";
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side note: You should usually enclose variables in quotation marks. `if [ $userid -lt 10]` will fail with an awkward syntax error if `$userid` happens to be empty, while `if ["$userid" -lt 10]` will say something more straightforward like "integer expression expected" if there's a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you wrote your `while` loop, you put `do` on its own line. `if` expects the same of `then`.

Wrong:

```
if [ blah ] then
```

Right:

```
if [ blah ]
  then
```

A lot of people find it bothersome to do this, so you can substitute a semicolon for the newline if you wish.

```
if [ blah ]; then
```

Comment: As a side note, the reason why the `then` has to be separated is because the syntax is `if` *command arg1 arg2 ...*.  The `[` is not part of the `if` it is a command.  The end of the `if` is marked by a newline or a semi-colon, if that was not the case it would have no idea if the `then` was part of the command.

Comment: @Silvio: Thank you for your answer!  You're right that is one of the errors.  Your codes are neat.  Now I can see that I have to put single space after if [ not if[.

Comment: @cdarke: Thanks for the elaboration!  Ah that's why. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer!  I noticed that there is no popular IDE for bash scripting.  However, I found a syntax checker!  I got help from https://www.shellcheck.net/.  All my errors were highlighted and explained why and how to resolved them just like an IDE.  Now it works flawlessly.  Happy!

```
#!/bin/bash

groupadd SC001
count=1
userid=$(find /home -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | wc -l)
echo "##Total user is ""$userid"

if [ "$userid" -lt 10 ]; then
    while [ $count -lt 10 ] 
        do
            useradd -m "s"$count"_2018"
            ((count+=1))
        done
fi

count=10
userid=$(find /home -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | wc -l)
if [ "$userid" -ge 10 ]; then
    while [ $count -le 25 ] 
        do
            useradd -m "s"$count"_2018"
            ((count+=1))
        done
fi
```